# Do these two expressions for correlation function have the same physical interpretation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, definition, path-integral, correlation-functions

I have learned that
the  $k$-point correlation function is
\begin{equation*}
\left<\Omega\left|T\prod_{n=1}^k\hat{\phi}(x)\right|\Omega\right> = \frac{1}{Z_0}\prod_{n = 1}^k\left(-i\frac{\delta}{\delta j(x_n)}\right)Z[j]\Big|_{j = 0}
\end{equation*}
with the generating functional
$$
Z[j] = \int\mathcal{D}[\phi]\exp\left(i\int d^4x[\mathcal{L}[\phi(x)]+j(x)\phi(x)]\right)
$$
However, sometimes I see the correlator written like
\begin{equation*}
\left<\Omega\left|T\prod_{n=1}^k\hat{\phi}(x)\right|\Omega\right> = \frac{1}{Z_0}\int\mathcal{D}[\phi]e^{i\int d^4x \mathcal{L}}\prod_{n = 1}^k\phi(x)
\end{equation*}
Where $Z_0 = Z[j=0]$. Although the two equations are equivalent, I'm not sure if they have the same physical interpretations. For example,
when solving P&S problem 11.1(a) (computing $\langle T e^{i\phi(x)}e^{-i\phi(0)}\rangle $), we can use the second form to write
$$
\langle T e^{i\phi(x)}e^{-i\phi(0)}\rangle = \int\mathcal{D}[\phi]e^{iS}e^{i\phi(x)}e^{-i\phi(0)} = ...
$$
Here the terms $e^{i\phi(x)}$ and $e^{-i\phi(0)}$ are called 'insertions' (I'm not quite clear what's the physical meanings of insertions either). When computing Feynman rules for scattering, however, I think the first one might be more useful.

Comment: Please provide a) definitions of your quantities (which probably would answer your question immediately) and b) sources/references.

Comment: I'm confused. The two ways to compute correlators from $Z[j]$ are one and the same. If you express $Z[j]$ as path integral you can evaluate the functional derivatives explicitly and you get the second equation. But you seem to be aware of that since you say that you know they are equivalently. What is your question then?

Comment: Also, regarding insertions, define a function $\langle\rangle$ taking operators at various spacetime points into numbers by $$\langle \phi(x_1)\cdots \phi(x_n)\rangle\equiv \langle \Omega |T\{\phi(x_1)\cdots \phi(x_n)\}|\Omega\rangle,$$ where $|\Omega\rangle$ is the vacuum of the theory (assumed non-degenerate to simplify things). Then any operator that you plug inside of $\langle\rangle$ is called an insertion.  You are literally picking $\langle\rangle$ and inserting things inside of it.

Comment: @Gold Thanks for the comment! So the 3-point function is just the insertion of 3 fields inside $\langle\rangle$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. This is just terminology for inserting things in some correlator. In this particular case a time-ordered correlator, but could also be for example a radially-ordered operator in a conformal field theory.

Comment: @Gold And my question is if the two forms of this equation are used for different purposes. Say for computing that quantity in my OP, we should use the second form, is that right?

Comment: They are one and the same morally. If you evaluate $\langle \phi(x_1)\cdots \phi(x_n)\rangle$ by taking functional derivatives of $Z[j]$ and you use its expression as a Fourier transform of a functional measure, you find out your second equation in two lines. So you should be fine in seeing they are the same thing for a monomial in the fields $\phi(x_1)\cdots \phi(x_n)$.

Comment: Next consider a more general functional $f[\phi]$ and assume it can be expressed even if just formally as a power series in the fields.  Then you reduce the computation f $\langle f[\phi]\rangle$ to $\langle \phi(x_1)\cdots \phi(x_n)\rangle$ and you again get the second expression.